# Create CSV from results of PHP prepared statement

Tags: php, csv, prepared-statement

Here is the code that fills in a table from a user search. Search function works perfectly. How can i use the same result set to dynamically generate a CSV? i.e. the user searches, then wants to download the results as CSV. There is a while loop running the search results into my table below the code block, so the query works great. Thanks for any help.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `contacts_main` WHERE `BUSINESS OR 
NAME` LIKE ? OR `NAME` LIKE ? OR `LAST NAME` LIKE ? OR `ADDRESS` LIKE ? OR 
`ADDRESS` LIKE ? OR `CITY` LIKE ? OR `STATE` LIKE ? OR `ZIP` LIKE ? OR 
`PHONE` LIKE ? OR `EMAIL` LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $param, $param, $param, $param, 
    $param, $param, $param, $param, $param, $param);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows === 0) exit('No Search Results');
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $businessorname, $name, $lastname, $address, 
    $city, $state, $zip, $phone, $email);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $searchresults = printf("Results found: %d.\n", $stmt->num_rows);
```

Here is some code using plain SQLi that i use to grab entire database & ive tried adapting it to the prepared statement with not results

```
 $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `contacts_main`");
 if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
 $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);
$headers = array();
while ($fieldinfo = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
    $headers[] = $fieldinfo->name;
}
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . date("Y-m-d") . '- 
    contacts-main-export-by-' . $uidName . '.csv');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    fputcsv($fp, $headers);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    } 
    die;
}
```

ok so this is the code im trying. i know the query goes through just fine but not sure how to loop through the results in a way that makes sense to a CSV format using the prepared statement results

```
    if (isset($_POST['create-csv-from-search-results'])) {

    $query = $_POST['query'];

    $param = "%{$query}%";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `contacts_main` WHERE `BUSINESS OR 
    NAME` LIKE ? OR `NAME` LIKE ? OR `LAST NAME` LIKE ? OR `ADDRESS` LIKE ? 
    OR `ADDRESS` LIKE ? OR `CITY` LIKE ? OR `STATE` LIKE ? OR `ZIP` LIKE ? 
    OR `PHONE` LIKE ? OR `EMAIL` LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $param, $param, $param, $param, $param, 
    $param, $param, $param, $param, $param);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows === 0) exit('No Search Results');
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $businessorname, $name, $lastname, $address, 
    $city, $state, $zip, $phone, $email);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $searchresults = printf("Results found: %d.\n", $stmt->num_rows);


    $headers = array();
    while ($fieldinfo = $stmt->fetch()) {

        $headers[] = $fieldinfo->name;

        }
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    if ($fp && $stmt) {

        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header('Expires: 0');
        fputcsv($fp, $headers);

     while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));

        } die;
      }
     }
```

Comment: Since the result set is an associative array, I'd simply iterate through it and use `fputcsv()` for each row. Have you considered this?

Comment: I have not. I do not know the correct syntax to do that. I know how to do it using plain SQLi but I want extra protection by working off this prepared statement.

Comment: `fputcsv()` is plain PHP. Please include your code you tried as part of the question and I'll show you how to fix the error.